# Site search return value after long time

Tags: magento-1.9

SIte search return value after long time, may result show or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors on which speed of load depends on

```
1) Store cache configuration
2) Number of products in catalog
3) Conflicts with custom extensions in Magento core
4) Power of your server
5) Usage of shared/managed server on which store is located
6) The traffic flow
7) The server location
8) Type and speed of the connection
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: am not hosting, just run my localhost, its takes at least 3 minutes to return values, how can i improve speed.